# filter a Linux log file using Python

Tags: python, regex, linux, filter

I want to filter a log file to keep all lines matching a certain pattern. I want to do this with Python.

Here's my first attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv 

script, filename = argv
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            e = line.index("some_term_I_want_to_match")
        except: 
            pass
        else:
            print(line)
```

How can I improve this to:

- save the result to a new file of similar name (i.e., a different extension)
- use regex to make it more flexible/powerful.

(I'm just learning Python. This question is as much about learning Python as it is about accomplishing this particular result.)

**OK, here's what I came up with so far...** But how do you do the equivalent of prepending an `r` as in the following line

```
re.compile(r"\s*")
```

where the string is **not** a string literal, as in the next line?

```
re.compile(a_string_variable)
```

Other than that, I think this updated version does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv 
import re
import os
import argparse #requires Python 2.7 or above

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='filters a text file on the search phrase')
parser.add_argument('-s','--search', help='search phrase or keyword to match',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-f','--filename', help='input file name',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-v','--verbose', help='display output to the screen too', required=False, action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()

keyword = args.search
original_file = args.filename
verbose = args.verbose

base_file, ext = os.path.splitext(original_file)
new_file = base_file + ".filtered" + ext

regex_c = re.compile(keyword)

with open(original_file) as fi:
    with open(new_file, 'w') as fo:
        for line in fi:
            result = regex_c.search(line)
            if(result):
                fo.write(line)
                if(verbose):
                    print(line)
```

Can this be easily improved?

Comment: Why not use `grep`? If you want to use regex and insist on writing this in Python, look at the `re` module.

Comment: No need for `try...except` here in my opinion.

Comment: I updated my question. And I want to do this in Python because I'm learning Python.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know, you have answered most of your questions yourself already :)

For regular expression matching use [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (the doc has pretty explanatory examples).

You already have made use `open()` function for opening a file. Use the same function for open files for writing, just provide a corresponding `mode` parameter ("w" or "a" combined with "+" if you need, see `help(open)` in the Python interactive shell). That's it.

Comment: ... and use the [os.path](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html) module to change the file extension.

Comment: Well, "improved" isn't a right word to describe your needs. If it does what you want, it shouldn't be improved. If you need smth else, you should formulate it explicitly. I would decrease the nesting level by merging both file opening in one statement, but this would require a object implementing [Context Manager protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers). Or simply use `try: f = open("original")... finally: f.close()...` which means almost the same as `with` statement